# Microsoft Azure: Service keeps saying Registering

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am trying to make a chat bot, but when I ty to publish it, it says Microsoft.Storage service provider is not registered.

When I check my services its stuck on "Registering", any idea how long will it take to register.

Answer (score 0):

*As mentioned in the error message, your Subscription does not have `Microsoft.Storage` registered as a Service provider.* You can ask the Admin to register `Microsoft.Storage` as a `Resource Provider` by following the steps mentioned in [Azure resource providers and types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-providers-and-types#azure-portal)